# How to avoid using function in ngStyle or ngClass?

Tags: angular, styles, ng-class, ng-style

This is an annoying issue if I can say so ... If  I use a method in the template, this will be called so many timesss.... due of the change detection of Angular.

3511 messages (method calls) in just 30 seconds, only for 12 items.

[image]

how my code looks initial: 
html:

```
<td *ngFor="let value of values"
      class="value">
    <span [ngStyle]="getValueStyle(value)">{{value}}</span>
  </td>
```

.ts:

```
getValueStyle(value: any) {
console.log(value);
let stringValue = value.toString();
if (!stringValue.includes('%')) return '';

let index = stringValue.indexOf('%');
let formatedNumber = stringValue.substring(0, index).replace(/\s/g, '');
let numberValue = Number(formatedNumber);
if (Number.isNaN(numberValue) || numberValue == 0) {
  return {'color': '#585858'};
} else if (numberValue > 0) {
  return {'color': '#009900'};
} else if (numberValue < 0) {
  return {'color': '#cc0000'};
}

return '';
```

}

To avoid using function in template, I declared 3 classes in .scss and made the verification in .html (can do it because is a simple comparison)

```
<td *ngFor="let value of values"
      class="value">
    <span [ngClass]="!value.includes('%')
      ? 'neutral'
      : value.includes('-')
          ? 'negative'
          : (value == '0')
            ? 'neutral'
            : 'positive'">{{value}}</span>
  </td>
```

But, if i need to compute a dynamic style, how can avoid these repeatedly calls?
Anyway, I don't know if using ngClass is a good solution instead ngStyle, because now, I can not see in console how many times this will be executed. Which is the best way to solve it?

Comment: may be predefined calculations before rendering it to the view, if possible.

Comment: You could use a pipe to reduce function calls

Comment: I know using pipe, its comportment is the same. For every mouse event, the pipe is executed

Comment: Did you try `pure`pipe? https://dzone.com/articles/why-we-shound-not-use-function-inside-angular-temp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you can "map" your array and convert it in an array of objects,e.g.

```
const listValues=this.values.map(x=>{
   return {
      value:x,
      style:this.getValueStyle(x)
   }
})
```

And use

```
<td *ngFor="let item of listValues"
      class="value">
    <span [ngStyle]="item.style">{{item.value}}</span>
  </td>
```

So, only call to getValueStyle so many times elements there are in your array "values"